# Is life in a supercritical fluid possible?

Tags: biochemistry

Someone claimed that the dinosaurs could only live because back then athmospheric density was around 650 kg/m³, providing some buyoncy, this claim is [checked on Skeptics SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19073/what-was-the-density-of-prehistoric-earth-atmosphere-dinosaurs-buoyancy-theory/20516). The claim itself is beside the point now. A simple calculation shows us that an atmsphere with this density would be [supercritical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercritical_fluid) in underwise normal conditions, the pressure would be increased by a factor of roughly 520. See my [answer to the skeptics question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/20516/16410) for a bit more explanation. I would say that a supercritical air atmosphere rules out life for several reasons:

- The high effusity of the fluid may mean that cell membranes don't work
- Proteins fold differently under high pressure, requiring specific adaptions
- If the partial pressure of oxygen is increased proportionally, the atmosphere is highly toxic
- If the partial pressure of oxygen remains at current levels, it is a trace gas and reactions relying on oxygen may run into kinetic problems (There may be a sweet spot between the last two issues)

Anyway, those are just my hunches, I never heard of experiments about life in supercritical fluids and I'm no biologist so my hunches may be totally wrong. My question is: **Can we rule out life in supercritical fluids;** if not **can we rule out air breathing, multi cellular animal life?**
Or has any life been shown to thrive in a supercritical fluid?

To stress again, the part with buoyant dinosaurs was given for background (and amusement), I'm only asking here to check my hunch that suprecriticality rules out life.